# Securing 3-3-3-5 SER at sub panel entrance

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

When installing a 100A sub-panel with larger wire (3-3-3-5 copper SER), is there a specific size of wire clamp I need for this? Do I use the same type of wire clamp as I would for NM cable, just larger (like the type that go into the knockout with a nut and have some screws to tighten the cable)? Is there a specific size of clamp I need?

I think the codes I've seen (which I haven't search through exhaustively) just say the wires need to be secured and follow the manufacturer guidelines or something. Would appreciate any specific parts I should buy.

Comment: Is this in conduit or just loose?

Comment: Go to the electrical supply house and they'll set you up.  It's just so typical of the big-box stores to cheerfully sell you the wire and not discuss box entry.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, they know how to measure wire, not what to do with it.  It's a DIY store after all!

Comment: Just loose, in-wall (the main and sub are mounted in the drywall so I didn't want to run conduit behind the drywall or go out/back in if I didn't have to). I guess I'll just make a trip one of these weekday mornings to an electrical store to ask.

Comment: Or the big box will gladly sell you pro-grade SER connectors... online only

Comment: @Machavity And the online UI will totally help you buy the wrong thing :)

Comment: I take it your jurisdiction bans aluminum wiring, or is there some other reason you're using copper for wires this fat?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you're looking at a larger NM clamp here

Looking at some sizing data, a 3-3-3-5 copper SER is [0.91" in diameter](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/copper-building-wire/ser-cable/3-3-3-5-copper-ser-service-entrance-cable.html).  This fits neatly into the .790-.980" cable range supported by an [Arlington 843S](http://www.aimedia.co/media/line-drawings/843S-849S.pdf) or equivalent 1" trade size NM/SE clamp.